# Meaning of * operator when used with classes

Tags: python

I've been trying to follow a video tutorial on Python and cannot understand one operation the developer performs.

```
class Polynomial():

    def __init__(self, *coeffs):
        self.coeffs = coeffs # (3,4,3)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Polynomial(*{!r})'.format(self.coeffs)

    def __add__(self, other):
        print(self.coeffs)
        print(other.coeffs)
        z = (x + y for x, y in zip(self.coeffs, other.coeffs))
        print(z)
        return Polynomial(*(x + y for x, y in zip(self.coeffs, other.coeffs)))

p1 = Polynomial(1, 2, 3) # x^2 + 2x + 3
p2 = Polynomial(3, 4, 3) # 3x^2 + 4x + 3
#print(p2) # Polynomial(*(3, 4, 3))
print(p1 + p2) # Polynomial(*(4, 6, 6))
```

The above example will print

```
<generator object Polynomial.__add__.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x030D0390>
```

as the return value of z, I cannot understand why because I am performing a zip operation of two tuples?

Alongside that problem, I do not understand why removing the `*` during the return of `__add__` causes a problem i.e `return Polynomial(*(x + y for x, y in zip(self.coeffs, other.coeffs)))` to `return Polynomial((x + y for x, y in zip(self.coeffs, other.coeffs)))`

**What is the * operator doing, and why is z an object of Polynomial?**

The `_add__` method does not contain a parameter containing a `*` or `**` and is therefore a different situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

So first.

Your print is ok. You defined a generator using () parentheses. You can change this to [] and then you should see the elements in list.

Or you can use your generator, so print:

```
print([el for el in z])
```

Second, the *.

It will simply pass iterable as separated args, so:

```
SomeClass(*args)
```

Will do:

```
SomeClass(args[0], args[1], args[2], ...)
```

You can read about this in official docs (single asterisk), here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists
And here (double asterisk): 
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays

Comment: or just print(list(z)). As to second question - you print the result of p1+p2 - i.e. print(p1 + p2). The __add__ method returns Polynominal object, so when you print it and because you don't have __str__ method, it calls the __repr__ method of Polynominal class

Answer (score 0):

**When in a function declaration, * is list of args send.**

For exemple:

```
def my_function(a, *b, **c):
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)

my_function("1st arg", "other arg", "other arg again", 2, arg_type="kwargs")
```

output :

```
1st args
["other arg", "other arg again", 2]
{"arg_type": "kwargs"}
```

**And when is not in function declaration, it's for unpack the list.**

For exemple:

```
list_of_arguments = ['a', 'b', 'z']
my_str = "the first letter of alphabet is {}, the second is {} and the last is {}"
print(my_str.format(*list_of_arguments))
```

or other exemple

```
 def my_second_func(a, b, c):
     print(a)
     print(b)

 my_list = [1, 2, 3]
 my_second_func(a, b, c)
```

will output:

```
 1
 2
```

Comment: but __add__ does not have a parameter with a *

Comment: i edited my post, in your code ``*`` is used for unpack the list returned by the zip() function

Answer (score 0):

Consider this easy example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

gen = (x + y for x, y in zip(a, b))

print(gen) ## this will print <generator object <genexpr> at 0x...>
```

In this case, the asterisk evaluates the generator expression. So when doing

```
print(*gen) ## this will print 5 7 9
```

you evaluate the generator expression.